# Can I externalize the Ionic2 components in another project?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I'm working on a project where one requirement is to use the Google's Material design. The other requirement is Angular2. Unfortunately the material design for NG2 isn't fully ready yet. Since in the past I've worked with Ionic2, I've seen that it has a huge library of components already set up with the material design (for android). I was wondering if there's some way to extract those components and re-use them inside another angular2 project...

Is it witchcraft? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a web project or a mobile project?
In any case you can't just extract a component, what you can do is use PWA [Ionic 2 - PWA forum post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/all-about-progressive-web-apps/52498), set you application mode to 'md' in you app.modules imports and then edit the remaining css to look more like material design

Comment: sorry for the long delay :D I've forgot to answer you back! Thanks a lot